# Determine the type of object (e.g. lines or plane) given the intersection

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, plane-geometry

Given B =\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 & 1\\ 1 & 1 & 3\end{pmatrix}determine the general solution of the homogeneous system B**x**=**0**. This describes the intersection of two objects (e.g. a line or a plane). Determine and find the Cartesian equation of this object.

I have solved the homogeneous equation being **x**$=t(-2, -1, 1)$ but how do I determine what two objects this intersection represents along with their Cartesian equation?

Comment: If you have a homogeneous system then the $\;2\times3\;$ matrix represents two planes in $;\Bbb R^3\;$ and thus either they're parallel or else they intersect in a line...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the first two columns are linearly independent, this means rank (dimension of the range space) is at least $2$. But range is $\subseteq \Bbb{R}^2$. Thus the range is entire $\Bbb{R}^2$. By the rank-nullity theorem, the nullity is $3-2=1$. This means the solution space for $B\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$ is $1$ dimensional. Thus it must be a line passing through the origin.

Note: we didn't have to really solve the system to determine the geometry of the solution space.

From your answer it is clear that any solution is parallel to the vector $\begin{bmatrix}-2\\-1\\1\end{bmatrix}$. Hence it is line whose direction vector is this and passes through the origin.